# What's the name of the property that leads to Newton's Fractal? For rational maps, regions contain either 1 limiting behavior or all

Tags: polynomials, fractals, newton-raphson

3Blue1Brown has 2 great videos on Newton's fractal. In [the second video](https://youtu.be/LqbZpur38nw?t=1274) he describe a property that makes it inevitable. Does this property/theorem have a name?

> For any rational map, if you were to
> assign colors to regions based on which limiting behavior points fall
> into ... then tiny circles that you draw either contain points with 1
> limiting behavior or all of them, never in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Theorem 3.9 (Transitivity) in the following [intro paper](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REUDOCS/Stoll.pdf).

[image]

The idea of *topological transitivity* is that the forward iterations of an open set end up filling up the space. In our application, this says that $U$ contains points arbitrarily close to the different roots of the polynomial, and we know that for such points the iteration just pulls them towards the respective root.